# stop automatic form refresh on submit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a contact formular using only html javascript and css. I know client-side validation is not what you should use nowadays, but I would like to understand it! It is not a contact formular thats going to be implemented in a site where security is important!

My whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/t59By/

For some reason the random numbers for my captcha are not displayed in fiddle but are displayed when i open it in my browser.

The problem I got is the automatic refresh after hitting submit. It occured after I took:

```
    action="MAILTO:example@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain"
```

out of my code... 
If i put it back in the refreshing stops but the email is send whether the form has been validated or not...

I already serached for a solution and found "return false" and cookies as an option. I tried both but failed to do so correctly it seems. 

How can I stop the automatic refresh and loss of field-input when the user hits the submit button? 
 Any thoughts are appreciated! 
 SOLVED: I just changed the input type from submit to button and now it works just fine! Thanks for all the help! I still appreciat ideas what could have caused it and what went wrong with my cookie try (first fiddle)... Thanks!

Comment: `randomNums is not defined` after submit `dcc is not defined`

Comment: I wrote the code using notepad++ and for me these errors dont show... It works fine (in firefox) but keeps refreshing after hitting submit...

Comment: You have many html/jscript errors. Try to work with a free HTML editor and check Fiddle tutorial to post code.

Comment: @Phx Can you point some html errors out? I checked with e.g. firebug and did not get an error? Also which js errors did you find? I know the part with the cookies doesnt work but the rest should be fine?

Comment: You can see the erros on your jsfiddle. Html erros are red. Firebug for javascript errors (like Uncaught ReferenceError: randomNums is not defined ). I'm talking about your jsfiddle.

Comment: Yeah the main errors in jsfiddle have nothing to do with the important code. The code where I tried to make the cookies work (any advice on that?) can be excluded, I dont use it because I didnt get it to work. And the other errors are "mixed spans and tabs". I just checked the fiddle and now it says "code is perfectly valid, however the errors are not displayed. And firebug doesnt show any errors

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/54Lpd/1/ my new code without all the stuff i dont need, if you want to take a look! :)

Answer (score 1):

replace the button on click functions with buttonclicked().

```
<input type="submit" onclick=" return buttonClickd();" value="Submit it!" id="button">
```

and code is

```
var flag;
function buttonClickd(){
    var flag = true;
    dcc (); hi1 (); hi2 (); hi3 (); hi4 (); hi5 (); hi6 (); hi7 (); hi8 (); emic (); pwic(); checkemail(); checkpw(); addNums(); ccb(); callEmail (); error ();
    if(flag)
        return flag;
    else{
        return flag;
        error();
    }
}
```

place flag = false; line when the above functions are not satisfied with the conditions. for example

```
var hi1 = function () {

    if ($('#input1').val() === "") {
        $('#input1').addClass('hi');
              flag = false;
        return;
        }
};
```

[Fiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/cbandi/t59By/4/).  I don't have tested your code because of captch. just modify your code related to the above conditions. I think you are that much capable to do those small things

Comment: I solved it by just changing the last input type from submit to a simple button! Thanks for your solution looks good to me, I might try it if i find the time! Do you have any idea why the captcha is not displayed in fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

This will show a demo -

http://jsfiddle.net/s68Ur/1/

Notice that you should `'return false`' in function and `"return s();"` in function call. The second return is must have. 
Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: I tried something like this but it didnt work, probably did not give all the functions a return false or so...

Comment: @user3568224 maybe, but it works in demo and if it works for you, you should accept it for others to know.

Answer (score 0):

Only possible way is using AJAX validation. in Ajax you have better control over forms than javascript. specially you can validate real-time and submit without leaving page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#formid").submit(function(event) { 
event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({

        url : 'example@example.com',
        data: {

        },
        success: function(response){
        alert ('Successfully registered');
      }
    })
});
})
```

you have to include bootstrap and ajax classes to activate above code. if you're not familiar with AJAX [Click here for simple tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery)

event.preventDefault(); is the key here. it prevents your page refreshing and will follow next ajax commands instead.

Hope this Helps..

Comment: Thanks! I have never used ajax before, just started to learn coding will definitely chek it out!

Answer (score 0):

As one commenter has pointed out, the code for the form is currently throwing some errors on variables which are not defined. If an error is occurring in the javascript for the page, this is almost certainly why you are getting the 'refresh' behaviour, as the browser will not reach your validation code when the submit button is pressed and will subsequently perform a standard postback.

The first thing I would recommend is testing your code locally. If you're not already doing so, try using the [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) extension for Firefox which will provide a javascript console to help you identify any errors on the form. Once you've ruled out any client script errors - you can move on to testing your validation logic.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi I am already using Firebug! It didnt show any errors while the refreshing happened. Solved the problem by changing the last input type from submit to button. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thats where my problem was and kinda still is. I circumvented the problem but still have no idea why the page started refreshing as soon as I took the mailto action out of the html page